# Selenium dll files for .NET

Tags: .net, dll, selenium-rc

I am installing Selenium to learn automation testing and I have selected C#.Net as my language. I downloaded the .Net client driver from this page - http://seleniumhq.org/download/ 
i.e. I downloaded:

[image]

Now when I am following the steps, it says that I need to create a class library in Visual Studio and then add reference to some NUnit and Selenium dll files. Well I installed NUnit, created the class library and when trying to reference the dll's I am not able to find few of them which are supposed to be added. If anybody has faced similar issue before or know where I can find these files then please help.

***Files to be added: -***

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_installing_dotnet_driver_client.html#configuring-selenium-rc-net-reference

[image]

***Dll's I have on my machine are:***

[image]

i.e. I only have ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll

I found NUnit.framework.dll and NUnit.nmock.dll in the NUnit folder.

```
Issue: I don't have or am not able to find the following dll's:
nunit.core.dll
nmock.dll
ThoughtWorks.Selenium.IntegrationTests.dll
ThoughtWorks.Selenium.UnitTests.dll.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you found where the assemblies are?

Answer (score 1):

It just happened that I was looking for the same thing and here it is,

https://github.com/schneems/Selenium-RC-Beta-2

You go here and download the zip file for the whole package.
Extract the zip file, and in the folder "selenium-dotnet-client-driver-1.0-beta-2" you have what you need.